# How to print a arrayline in seperate line in a TEXT FILE

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have to print a Array List in a text file. I need a output in separate line but I got in same line.

Example:
        My expected output in text file:
                             bat
                             ball
                             print
        my actual output is :
                        [bat,ball,print]

my console it print line by line
anyone help me to out of this issue
thank you

Comment: Can you please share the code you used to print that array to the file ?

Comment: @Syed here we appreciate others help and work by up voting and accepting the solution that worked for you. It should not be like getting your answer and running away. Should always appreciate others taking their time out to help you.

Comment: apologise for my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could give your code. But here is the code assuming strings are in ArrayList

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestJava{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add("bat");
        values.add("ball");
        values.add("print");
        BufferedWriter wr = null;
        try {
            wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
            for (String var : values) {
                wr.write(var);
                wr.newLine();
            }
            wr.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fout.writeChars()` everytime, you call this a new line will be printed. Just loop through your list and print one by one.

```
try{

DataOutputStream fout = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream("Lines.Txt")));
fout.writeChars("This is first line");
fout.writeChars("This is second line");
fout.close();

}
catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("Exception occured..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this sample code is working.

```
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
    sample.add("sample");
    sample.add("sample1");
    sample.add("sample2");
    sample.add("sample3");
    ;
    System.out.println(sample.stream().map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String data= null;
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add("test");
test.add("test1");
test.add("test2");
test.add("test3");

    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME));
        for(String testList : test) {
        data = testList;

        bw.write(data);
        bw.newLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
    bw.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution to what I understood your problem was:

```
        List<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
        sample.add("foo");
        sample.add("bar");
        sample.add("bizz");
        sample.add("bazz");

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
        sample.stream().forEach(s -> {
            System.out.println(s);
            try {
                writer.write(s + '\n');
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        writer.close();
```

First it adds some strings to the list.
The stream and forEach are the functional way to do iteration nowadays.
Then you write to file.